# How to get difference between $timeNow and $timeFuture?

Tags: php, laravel, momentjs, php-carbon

How to get difference between $timeNow and $timeFuture with Laravel and display in format "H:i:s" ?

Or how to make countdown with JS from $timeNow to $timeFuture and display in format "H:i:s" ?

Comment: Docs? http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-difference

Comment: @lesssugar Yes but how to display in "H:i:s" format  with Carbon?

Comment: Try chaining it with `->format('H:i:s')`.

Answer (score 2):

Using Carbon's [**`diffInSeconds`**](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-difference) method and [**`gmdate()`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gmdate.php), you can get it like this:

```
$timeNow = \Carbon::now();
$timeFuture = \Carbon::now()->addSeconds(7500);

echo gmdate("H:i:s", $timeNow->diffInSeconds($timeFuture));
```